# Wpf is blank at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a WPF with 2 simple buttons. In the IDE, it shows how the buttons will be displayed at runtime, exept that the runtime version is completely blank. I don't know how to fix that, and i'm growing pretty tired of it. Here is my MainWindow.xaml :

```cs
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="#2e5eaa"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="8M6B"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       
                       FontWeight="Medium"/>


            <Button
                Content="Site web"
                Foreground="White"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Background="Transparent"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Light"
                >

            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <!--<Image Width="70" Height="70" Source="img/86noice.png"
                       Margin="10,10,0,0"/>-->
                <TextBlock Text="8M6B"
                           Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontWeight="Medium"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Bonjour et bienvenue sur 8 Morts 6 Blesses !"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="25"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="180">

                <Button x:Name="BtnConnect" Content="Se connecter"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="14"
                    FontWeight="Medium" Height="37" Width="137"
                    Background="#222222"
                    Margin="0,0,20,0">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="12"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>

                <Button  Content="S'inscrire"
                        Click="btnFatInscription_Click"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="14"
                    FontWeight="Medium" Height="37" Width="138"
                    Background="#FF934F"
                        Margin="20,0,0,0">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="12"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>



        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And the preview in Visual Studio 2022 :
[image]

[image]

An here is the actual WPF window that opens at runtime

Comment: Have you tried with a simpler layout? Like just `<Grid><Button>Test</Button></Grid>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attached an event to your button:

```
Click="btnFatInscription_Click"
```

But this event does not exist in your code behind.